# How to loop if there are multiple variables?

Tags: powershell

For example

```
a = @(

"test1",

"test2"

)

b = @(

"test3",

"test4"

)
```

​

one is

```
foreach ($c in $a) {

ehco $c

}
```

What should I do if I have more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a foreach on more than one object. You can do a for loop, but it will break if the arrays are not of the same size
Here's an example with a check on the arrays size:

```
if ($a.Count -eq $b.Count)
{
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $a.count; $i++)
    {
        $a[$i]
        $b[$i]
    }
}
```

Comment: What if b is greater than a?

Answer (score 1):

Or create an ([ordered](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables#creating-ordered-dictionaries)) [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables):

```
$hashtable = [Ordered]@{ a = @("test1", "test2"); b = @("test3", "test4") }
foreach ($Key in $HashTable.Keys) {
    foreach ($Item in $HashTable[$Key]) {
        echo $Item
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$a = @(
"test1",
"test2"

)
$b = @(
"test3",
"test4"
)
foreach ($c in ($a,$b)) {
    echo $c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the arrays and then loop through each item.

```
$a = @(

"test1",

"test2"

)

$b = @(

"test3",

"test4"

)

foreach($item in ($a + $b))
{
write-host $item
}
```

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = @("test1","test2"); $b = @("test3","test4")
$a,$b | % {$_}

test1
test2
test3
test4
```